# Recover a longer list of recent files from the Matlab editor

Tags: matlab, file, editor

I have lost the location of a `.m` file I recently wrote with the Matlab editor. I don't remember how I named it so the usual finder search is not helping.

The Matlab editor lets me open 'recent files' but only the few newest. Is there a way to recover a longer list of recently opened files?

Comment: You can increase the size of the recent file list in the preferences. Or do you mean to obtain those file names programmatically?

Comment: @LuisMendo I meant programmatically, and *a posteriori*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That information seems to be stored in the [Matlab preference folder](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/recovering-previous-editor-state). That folder is given by the function [`prefdir`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/prefdir.html).
Specifically, the file `'matlab.prf'` seems to contain the list of recent files. To open that file and inspect it manually you can use

```
open(fullfile(prefdir, 'matlab.prf'))
```

Recent file information seems to be contained in lines beginning with `EditorMRU`. I have observed that in R2010b and R2014b. Other Matlab versions may behave differently.

You could also programmatically read that file with [`importdata`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html),

```
x = importdata(fullfile(prefdir, 'matlab.prf')); %// R2010b or R2014b
x = x.textdata; %// include this line if using R2014b; not if using 2010b
```

This gives `x` as a cell array of strings, where each string is a line of that file. Then look for lines containing the substring `'EditorMRU'`:

```
y = x(~cellfun(@isempty, strfind(x, 'EditorMRU')));
```

I don't know how many recent file names are stored, though.

Comment: I'm not sure in what version of MATLAB the practice started, but when you run a function or script by using F5 or the main GUI's Run button it's automatically entered into the command history (and it's obviously going to be in there if you entered it explicitly), located in the same folder as `history.m` and `history.xml`. You could go through that as well if you have a general idea of the time window, the history tends to go back pretty far.

Comment: @CapeCode Here's a related question that has just been posted. The answer uses a slightly different approach. http://stackoverflow.com/q/28669347/2586922