# History of previously opened m-files in MATLAB

Tags: history, matlab

Is anyway to find history of previously opened m-files in MATLAB R2014b from 2 or 3 months ago? (a list of name of files and paths)

Comment: That's an interesting question.  I'd like to know the answer to this as well.

Comment: Related: [Recover a longer list of recent files from the Matlab editor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28587501/2586922)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Matlab R2014b stores its recent files in:

```
%APPDATA%\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2014b\MATLAB_Editor_State.xml
```

It's a `.xml` file so it's easy to load and parse with `xmlread`. I'm not very familiar with xml parsing syntax, but here is how to get information about files (to be adapted to your needs of course):

```
function [recentFiles] = GetRecentFiles()
%[
    % Opens editor's state file
    filepart = sprintf('MathWorks\\MATLAB\\R%s\\%s', version('-release'), 'MATLAB_Editor_State.xml');
    filename = fullfile(getenv('APPDATA'), filepart);
    document = xmlread(filename);

    % Get information about 'File' nodes
    recentFiles = struct([]);
    fileNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('File');
    for fni = 1:(fileNodes.getLength())

       attributes = fileNodes.item(fni-1).getAttributes(); % Careful, zero based indexing !

       for ai = 1:(attributes.getLength())

           % Get node attribute
           name = char(attributes.item(ai-1).getName()); % Zero based + need marshaling COM 'string' type
           value = char(attributes.item(ai-1).getValue()); % Zero based + need marshaling COM 'string' type

           % Save in structure
           name(1) = upper(name(1)); % Just because I prefer capital letter for field names ...
           recentFiles(fni).(name) = value;

       end

    end    
%]
end
```

This returns a structure like this:

```
recentFiles = 

1x43 struct array with fields:

    AbsPath
    LastWrittenTime
    Name
```

NB: I've tried to type in matlab command window `matlab.desktop.editor.*`, but seems there's nothing regarding recent files *(anyway there are a lot of interesting things to manipulate the editor from the command line)*

Comment: Thank you for answer. This is the last 50 files we loaded. Can we have a history with older files?

Comment: I don't think Matlab keeps an infinite history ... your only solution would be to look at windows recent files (e.g. [Windows7](http://www.itsupportguides.com/windows-7/windows-7-recent-items-folder-location/))

Answer (score 2):

Last answer waIs really helpful. I've just modified it to read and open the recent tab files. This works on Matlab R2013a:

```
function [recentFiles] = recover_tabs()
%[
% Opens editor's state file
filepart = sprintf('MathWorks\\MATLAB\\R%s\\%s', version('-release'), 'MATLAB_Editor_State.xml');
filename = fullfile(getenv('APPDATA'), filepart);
document = xmlread(filename);

% Get information about 'File' nodes
recentFiles = struct([]);
fileNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('File');
for fni = 1:(fileNodes.getLength())

   attributes = fileNodes.item(fni-1).getAttributes(); % Careful, zero based indexing !

   for ai = 1:(attributes.getLength())

       % Get node attribute
       name = char(attributes.item(ai-1).getName()); % Zero based + need marshaling COM 'string' type
       value = char(attributes.item(ai-1).getValue()); % Zero based + need marshaling COM 'string' type

       % Save in structure
       name(1) = upper(name(1)); % Just because I prefer capital letter for field names ...
       recentFiles(fni).(name) = value;

   end

end    

%     loop to access files in the tab history
for j=1:length(recentFiles)
    arquivo = [recentFiles(j).AbsPath '\' recentFiles(j).Name];
%         if exists, then open
    if exist(arquivo, 'file') == 2
        open(arquivo);
    end
end

%]
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that, helped me recover my opened .m files

Answer (score 2):

Base in the answer by CitizenInsane, but for any Matlab version.

To find the `.xml` file in any Matlab version, use `prefdir`:

```
>> prefdir

ans =  '/Users/user/Library/Application Support/MathWorks/MATLAB/R2018a'
```

`MATLAB_Editor_State.xml` will be stored there. Therefore the fuction would be:

```
function [recentFiles] = GetRecentFiles()

% Opens editor's state file
filepart = sprintf([ prefdir '/MATLAB_Editor_State.xml']);
filename = fullfile(getenv('APPDATA'), filepart);
document = xmlread(filename);

% Get information about 'File' nodes
recentFiles = struct([]);
fileNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('File');
for fni = 1:(fileNodes.getLength())

   attributes = fileNodes.item(fni-1).getAttributes(); % Careful, zero based indexing !

   for ai = 1:(attributes.getLength())

       % Get node attribute
       name = char(attributes.item(ai-1).getName()); % Zero based + need marshaling COM 'string' type
       value = char(attributes.item(ai-1).getValue()); % Zero based + need marshaling COM 'string' type

       % Save in structure
       name(1) = upper(name(1)); % Just because I prefer capital letter for field names ...
       recentFiles(fni).(name) = value;

   end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

In R2018b you can increase the `Most recently used file list` in `Preferences > Editor/Debugger`. I like the methods above, but they do not work if you're working across machines (e.g., using Github). [I coded a solution](http://gaidi.ca/weblog/list-or-edit-recently-modified-files-in-matlab) that uses the modified file date from the machine, instead of relying on MATLAB itself.